# Copy doubles and integers from one list to another using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object of type scenario that contains a list of objects type SN. There is another object of type scenarioSchema that also contains a list of objects type SNSchema.

I want to copy items (Doubles and Integers) from type SNSchema into type SN of object scenario.

```
scenario.V = new List<SN>();
scenario.V.Add(scenarioSchema.V.Select(x => x.Distro);


public class SN
{
    public double Version { get; set; }
    public int Distro { get; set; }
}
```

I know this behavior can be achieved through LINQ, basically what I want to do is to go through the whole list of items SNSchema and pass those to the list of object scenario.

I know this might be too simple, but I can't wrap my head around this.

Thanks,

Comment: did you try scenario.V.AddRange method to add multiple objects in list?

Comment: `scenario.V.AddRange(scenarioSchema.V.Select(x => new SN() { Distro = x.Distro}));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`AddRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
scenario.V.AddRange(scenarioSchema.V.Select(x => new SN() { Distro = x.Distro}));
```